# Javascript validation for entering text up to maximum length

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to validate a textbox which allows text to be entered up to 128 charecters only. But the code is unable to validate the text if I press the key and hold it without key up, allowing filling of the textbox above 128 chars. The validation works when I key up, popping up the alert. Below is the code.

```
  (textboxentered.value>128)
  {
    alert("Please enter text upto 128 Charecters");
  }
```

What I want is a solution such that when a key is pressed so long without key up, the text box should not allow more than 128 characters.

Comment: What other technologies are you using?

Comment: Please post a complete code example and if possible, an example at jsFiddle.net

Comment: How is this validation hooked up?

Comment: Why not just set a fixed size on the textbox?

Comment: I am using Struts HTML tags. Once I tried using the maxlength attrbute of textbox but it didn't work. Will this attribute works well

Comment: @Madbreaks, I have used the exact word in the title and tag. Are you just telling me use the tags in titles properly in future or have u found any incorrect usage here in my question??.

Comment: @ Jack: I am using JSP for view with Struts textbox tags. and validation using javascript

Comment: @user2105539 No, your title was fixed by another member here.  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15280186/revisions

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use the maxlength HTML property?

```
<input type="text" name="textbox" maxlength="128">
```

Comment: this code is not working when a key is pressed so long without key up. I am using struts, will there be any property of struts in html text tag such that i obtain the validation

Answer (score -1):

You can use x.length to get the length of the string and compare

```
if (textboxentered.value.lenght>128)   {
    alert("Please enter text upto 128 Charecters");   
}
```

Comment: This answer lacks explanation. Pls explain it.

Comment: You can use x.length to get the length of the string and compare

Comment: You need to edit the answer and add explanation and format it too.